# c++ destructor in linked lists

Tags: c++, linked-list

I Have built a stack using linked lists in c++, but I was being told that the whole thing is worthless since my destructor is not doing its job efficiently , so can anybody tell me how can I build a destructor for this code. It was my understanding that a constructor work is to delete the memory that is unused, is there any other function of the destructor that that I mentioned ? 
any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

class Stack
{
private:
    struct node
    {
        int data;
        node* next;

        node()
        {
          int data = 0;
          next = nullptr;
        }

    };
node* top;
public:
    Stack()
    {
        top = nullptr;
    }
    ~Stack()
    {
       delete top;
    }
 void push(int n)
 {
    node* temp = new node;
    temp->data = n;
    temp->next = top;
    top = temp; 
 }

    int pop()
    {
        node* temp = top;
        top = top->next;
        return temp->data;
    }

    int peek()
    {
        return top-> data;
    }

    bool isEmpty()
    {
        return top == 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Stack stack;

    std::string command;

    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "stack>";
        std::cin >> command;
        try
        {
            if (command == "pop")
            {
                if (stack.isEmpty())
                {
                    throw std::runtime_error("error: stack is empty");
                }
                 std::cout << stack.pop() << std::endl;
            }

            else if (command == "push")
            {
                int n;
                if (!(std::cin >> n))
                {
                    throw std::runtime_error("error: not a number");
                }
                stack.push(n);
            }

            else if (command == "peek")
            {
                if (stack.isEmpty())
                {
                     throw std::runtime_error("error: stack is empty");
                }
                std::cout << stack.peek() << std::endl;
            }

             else if (command == "end")
            {
                 while (!(stack.isEmpty()))
                 {
                    std::cout << stack.pop() << std::endl;
                 }
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("error: invalid command");
            }
        }
        catch (std::runtime_error& e)
        {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            std::cerr << std::endl << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you missing `node` destructor?

Comment: yes I'm Sorry my bad 
I have included my destructor now

Comment: "_It was my understanding that a constructor work is to delete the memory that is unused_" It seems that you have constructors mixed up with destructors. Since it's the job of a destructor to free-up all the resources used by instance, when it is being deallocated.

Comment: @salva 
No infact the destructor of the Stack should be different

Comment: @UmarSheikhZombiez You can't just delete the head of the nodes. That will free memory associated with that node, but the entire rest of the list still needs to be freed, and without a pointer to the rest of the list, you can't free it.

Comment: Your stack destructor only deletes the top node. What about all the others?

Comment: Fix the destructor. Then ask for a review at https://codereview.stackexchange.com there are a couple of more issues.

Answer (score 1):

You have memory leak in `Stack::pop()` method and your `Stack()` destructor only deletes `top` so if you have more than 1 elements you would have yet another leak. When you deal with dynamically allocated memory you better use smart pointers:

```
class Stack
{
    struct node;
    using node_ptr = std::unique_ptr<node>;
private:
    struct node
    {
        int data;
        node_ptr next;

        node(int n, node_ptr nxt) : data(n), next( std::move(nxt) )
        { // your old ctor has a bug, you "initialized" local variable
        }
    };

    node_ptr top;
    Stack() = default;
    ~Stack()
    {
         while(top)
             top = std::move( top->next );
    }

    int pop()
    {
       node_ptr temp = std::move(top);
       top = std::move(temp->next);
       return temp->data;
    }

    void push(int n)
    {
        top = std::make_unique<node>(n,std::move(top));
    }

    int peek() const
    {
        return top->data;
    }

    bool isEmpty() const
    {
       return !top;
    }
};
```

your code becomes smaller and easier to understand and free from leaks you had before. You do not have to provide explicit `Stack` destructor, but it would be inefficient (doing recursive call but still correct). Provided destructor just more efficient.

Comment: @Kevin as I mentioned in the answer default dtor would work, but it is recursive, so it could be not efficient  and it is possible to get out of stack if there are too many elements.

Comment: @Kevin the explicit destructor shown here is not just more efficient (in terms of speed). It's crucially more efficient in use of stack space. A recursion depth that is linear in the size of the structure will easily overflow the limited stack of a typical process if the list is long. (unless the recursion is tail-call optimized, but you cannot rely on optimization since you probably want to run debug builds as well).

Comment: Ah true. That's what I get for not reading the full answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a list like this:

```
top---->node->node->node->node->...
```

In the destructor of `Stack`, you delete the object pointed by `top`. What you're left with is:

```
              node->node->node->...
```

Notice that most of the nodes have not been deleted, and since nothing points to them anymore, there is no longer a way to delete them. This is called a memory leak.

To fix the destructor, you must delete each node on the list. Hint: Use a loop; make a copy of the next pointer, delete the current node and move on to the next one.

---

The destructor is not the only place where the stack leaks. `pop` fails to delete the top node before unlinking it from the list.

Furthermore, assigning or coping a `Stack` object will cause the both objects to have the same list and consequently attempt to delete it twice (once in each of the respective object's destructor). The behaviour will be undefined. Whenever you manage resources in the destructor, you always need to define a copy (and move) constructor and assignment operators that manage the resources also. This is called the rule of 3 (5 for move operations). You can declare them deleted if you don't want the class to be copyable (or movable).

It is a bad design to have owning bare pointers. A better design is to use `std::unique_ptr`

Your constructor of `node` leaves `data` member uninitialized. I don't think your stack ever reads a default initialized node, so that might not be a problem, but you may have different expectations for the constructor that you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You need to deallocate memory for while link list :

```
~Stack()
    {
        while(top)
        {
            struct node* curr = top;
            top = top->next;
            delete curr;
        }
        top = nullptr;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting only the top element.

Try adding `~node() { delete next; }` to your `node` struct.

And make sure that it's `NULL`-terminated, so that it halts!